# Optimize clothes choice with respect to style points and cost

Tags: optimization

Given the following, how would you optimize the "style points" while staying under maximum cost? You must take 1 item from each class, and 2 separate items from class "accessories".

costlimit=100

Class: item:(style points, cost)

Pants: jeans:(5, 25), khakis:(3, 15), shorts:(2, 10)
Tops: tshirt1:(5, 28), tshirt2:(4, 20), tshirt3:(2, 10)
Shoes: shoes1:(8, 50), shoes2:(4,30), shoes3:(2,15)
Accessories: Acc1:(1,5), Acc2:(1, 4), Acc3:(2,6), Acc4:(3, 9), Acc5:(4,15)

I tried to find the name for this problem, and I think it is a spin on the 0-1 knapsack problem.

Comment: It's not a variant on, it is a [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). Your cost is your weight, your style points are the value.

Answer (score 0):

It's an optimization problem maybe you want linear algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Such problems can be modelled and solved using a constraint solver like [MiniZinc](http://www.minizinc.org/).

**My attempt:**

```
int: Jeans   = 1;
int: Khakis  = 2;
int: Shorts  = 3;
int: Tshirt1 = 4;
int: Tshort2 = 5;
int: Tshirt3 = 6;
int: Shoes1  = 7;
int: Shoes2  = 8;
int: Shoes3  = 9;
int: Acc1    = 10;
int: Acc2    = 11;
int: Acc3    = 12;
int: Acc4    = 13;
int: Acc5    = 14;

set of int: Items = Jeans .. Acc5;
set of int: Pants = Jeans .. Shorts;
set of int: Tops = Tshirt1 .. Tshirt3;
set of int: Shoes = Shoes1 .. Shoes3;
set of int: Accessories = Acc1 .. Acc5;

array[Items] of int: Costs;
array[Items] of int: StylePoints;
array[Items] of string: Names;

int: Costlimit = 100;
Costs       = [25,15,10,28,20,10,50,30,15, 5, 4, 6, 9,15];
StylePoints = [5 , 3, 2, 5, 4, 2, 8, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4];
Names = ["Jeans","Khakis","Shorts",
         "Tshirt1","Tshort2","Tshirt3",
         "Shoes1","Shoes2","Shoes3",
         "Acc1","Acc2","Acc3","Acc4","Acc5"];

array[Items] of var 0 .. 1: Select;

%%  take 1 item from each class
constraint 
    1 = sum(i in Pants)(Select[i]);

constraint 
    1 = sum(i in Tops)(Select[i]);

constraint 
    1 = sum(i in Shoes)(Select[i]);

%%  take 2 separate items from accessories
constraint 
    2 = sum(i in Accessories)(Select[i]);

%%  stay in budget
constraint
    Costlimit >= sum(i in Items)(Select[i] * Costs[i]);

%%  maximize style points
solve maximize 
    sum (i in Items) (Select[i] * StylePoints[i]);

%
%  Output solution as table of variable value assignments
%%
output 
["\nSelected items:"] ++
["\n" ++ show(Names[i]) ++ ": " 
      ++ show(Select[i]) 
      ++ "( style " ++ show(StylePoints[i]) 
      ++ "; cost " ++ show(Costs[i]) ++ ")" | i in Items] ++
["\n"] ++
["\nCosts:        " ++ show(sum(i in Items)(Select[i] * Costs[i]))] ++
["\nStyle points: " ++ show(sum(i in Items)(Select[i] * StylePoints[i]))];
```

I have used an array of `[0..1]` integers as decision variables. An array element is `1`, if the corresponding item is selected. Otherwise it is `0`. *MiniZinc* is capable to find solution - if it exists - which meets all given constraints and maximizes a target value.

**The generated solution:**

```
Selected items:
Jeans: 1( style 5; cost 25)
Khakis: 0( style 3; cost 15)
Shorts: 0( style 2; cost 10)
Tshirt1: 0( style 5; cost 28)
Tshort2: 0( style 4; cost 20)
Tshirt3: 1( style 2; cost 10)
Shoes1: 1( style 8; cost 50)
Shoes2: 0( style 4; cost 30)
Shoes3: 0( style 2; cost 15)
Acc1: 0( style 1; cost 5)
Acc2: 0( style 1; cost 4)
Acc3: 1( style 2; cost 6)
Acc4: 1( style 3; cost 9)
Acc5: 0( style 4; cost 15)

Costs:        100
Style points: 20
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is conceptually very helpful,but are you using python in this script? I've never seen the int: "name"=1; notation before and am not sure what you're doing. When i run it in python 2.7.8 i get syntax errors at the colon following the int

Comment: @akhan66: my script is written in "MiniZinc", the input language of the MiniZinc solver. In Python, you could use the Python package of the Microsoft Z3 solver. A brute-force solution would just enumerate all 2^14 selection options and take the best.

Comment: Or you can use Numberjack (http://numberjack.ucc.ie/) to model your problem in Python and use any of the supported CP solvers.